# Providing context in Dagger Hilt?

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-hilt

I found it in our codebase and don't know what to think about it. It seems a bit fishy and I reckon it's not appropriate to use.

What do we get from providing context this way besides not having to use the `@ApplicationContext` annotation as a result of this?

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object XModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideContext(@ApplicationContext context: Context): Context {
        return context
    }
...
```

What do you think of this approach?

Comment: None. If you never use @ ActivityContext and have a strict rule to never use @ ActivityScoped bindings then it might be excusable but it introduces a thing you have to remember about the codebase - bad. Definitely a code smell.